# Is there an algorithm for encoding two text and the result will be the same even if change their position?

Tags: sql, algorithm

May be the question is hard to understand, I mean this

Given two sample text

> Text1 = "abc" and Text2 = "def"

Which algorithm can do like

> encoding(Text1, Text2) == encoding(Text2, Text1)

And I wish the result of the function is unique(not duplicate with encoding(Text3, Text1) like in another checksum algorithm too.

Actually, the root of this is I want to search in my database for the question is there any rows that "Who is a friends of B" or "B is a friends of whom" by searching only one column like

```
SELECT * FROM relationship WHERE hash = "a039813"
```

not

```
SELECT *
FROM relationship
WHERE (personColumn1 = "B" and verb = "friend") OR
      (personColumn2 = "B" and verb = "friend")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adapt any encoding to ensure `encoding(Text1, Text2) == encoding(Text2, Text1)` by simply enforcing a particular ordering of the arguments. Since you're dealing with text, maybe use a basic lexical order:

```
encoding_adapter(t1, t2)
{
    if (t1 < t2)
        return encoding(t1, t2)
    else
        return encoding(t2, t1)
}
```

---

If you use a simple single-input hash function you're probably tempted to write:

```
encoding(t1, t2)
{
    return hash(t1 + t2)
}
```

But this can cause collisions: encoding("AA", "B") == encoding("A", "AB"). There are a couple easy solutions:

- if you have a character or string that never appears in your input strings then use it as a delimiter:

`return hash(t1 + delimiter + t2)`

- hash the hashes:

`return hash(hash(t1) + hash(t2))`

Comment: Thanks. What about the uniqueness, if my encoding is concatenate string it will be not unique like "AA" + "B" == "A" + "BB"

Comment: What do you mean? `encode_cat_adapter("AA", "B") = strcat("AA", "B") = "AAB"`. `encode_cat_adapter("B", "AA") = strcat("AA", "B") = "AAB"`. I don't see how "AA" turns into "A" and "B" into "BB".

Comment: Oh, my fault, I mean username "AA" and "B" is the same as username "A" and "AB" (strcat("AA", "B") == strcat("A", "AB"))

Comment: Thank you for a simple answer!